# I couldn't get the data from postman in my Spring boot project?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, postman

Table is created when I'm running the spring project but when I get the values from postman
It says 500 internal server error

1. Bookmark class

[image: Bookmark Class]

2.. Bookmark controlller
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the BookmarkController class add @Autowired for the instance of bookmarkService. And try to use the void method for functions that add data to the database. There is no need for returning anything from those functions